# Сравнить два словаря с помощью параметризации и фикстур

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Есть два словаря которые надо подробно сравнить (какие конкретно элементы отличаются) с помощью `@pytest.fixture(session='scope')` и `@pytest.mark.parametrize`.

`@pytest.fixture(session='scope')` применял для получение словарей

```
@pytest.fixture(session='scope')
def get_first_dic():
    ...
    return first_dic

@pytest.fixture(session='scope')
def get_decond_dic():
    ...
    return second_dic
```

Далее с помощью параметризации пытаюсь их сравнить (хотя бы полностью, без детализации)

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("get_first_dic, get_second_dic", (get_first_dic, get_second_dic))
def test_dbs(get_first_dic, get_second_dic):
    assert get_first_dic == get_second_dic
```

На что получаю [это](https://pastebin.com/HXcGwssc)

Также пытался сравнивать отдельно значения этих словарей, без ключей.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("get_first_dic, get_second_dic", ([i for i in get_first_dic().values()],
                                                           [i for i in get_first_dic().values()]))
def test_dbs(get_first_dic, get_second_dic):
    assert get_first_dic == get_second_dic
```

Здесь же проблема в том, что нельзя обращаться к фикстурам, как к функциям.

Каким образом это реализовать?

P.S. безусловно это можно сделать проще без pytest, но мне нужно с ним.

Comment: А зачем вы используете и параметризацию, и фикстуры? По идее так должно быть: https://pastebin.com/1AhsWQ7q

Comment: @insolor да, если бы не параметризация и фикстуры я бы так и сделал, и это было бы проще, но задание есть задание.

Comment: Возможно вы как-то не так поняли задание. Фикстуры не нужно вызывать напрямую. Они выполняются один раз, а потом просто по имени подставляются в параметры тестовых функций. Если вы их вызываете для получения набора параметров, то это уже не фикстура, а просто функция.